# Размер контейнера, равный максимальному эл-ту среди других детей (Bootstrap 3, CSS)

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, asp.net-core

Здравствуйте!

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать автоматическую установку размеров детей A, B, C, D равными максимальным размерам среди детей в родительском контейнере P?**

В A, B, C, D находятся различные текстовые элементы с relative позиционированием и некоторые элементы с абсолютным (это можно изменить если что). Т.е в ниже приведенном случае, размеры контейнеров A, C, D Должны стать такими же, как у B. Желательно увидеть ваш пример с решением, чисто через CSS (Полагаю, что это возможно сделать через flex-боксы, но не могу понять как), 
Cпасибо!

UPD: уточнение:
 У контейнеров A,B,C,D размеры рассчитываются по содержимому, ну и нужно сделать так, чтобы размеры всех четырех контейнеров (ширина и высота) имели максимальные значения, среди всех детей, таким образом будет эффект, что все контейнеры ВСЕГДА будут одинакового размеры - ровные и у них ничего не будет заезжать куда не нужно. По заданию должно быть четыре контейнера, расстояния между которыми должно быть одинаковым и сами они должны быть одинакового размера (но так, чтобы текст нигде не наезжал друг на друга). Все это истекает из проблем, появляющихся на маленьких устройствах (См. Фото)

```
css:
.container-analysis {
    background-color: #E6EAED;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #878787;
    font-weight: bold;
    min-height: min-content;
}

.container-analysis label {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container-analysis > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 0;
}

HTML A, B, C, D имеет такую структуру:
<div class="container-analysis">
        <label>ТЕКСТ, РАЗНОЙ ДЛИНЫ</label>
        <div>
            <span class="pull-left">@Model.PageModel.AverageSales</span>
            @if (Model.PageModel.AverageSalesPercent > 0)
            {
                <span class="glyphicon pull-right arrow-up" style="color: green;"></span>
                <span class="pull-right" style="color: green;">+@Model.PageModel.AverageSalesPercent%</span>
            }
            else if (Model.PageModel.AverageSalesPercent < 0)
            {
                <span class="glyphicon pull-right arrow-down" style="color: darkred;"></span>
                <span class="pull-right" style="color: darkred;">@Model.PageModel.AverageSalesPercent%</span>
            }
            else
            {
                <span class="glyphicon pull-right arrow-up-down" style="color: #1f0dc2;"></span>
                <span class="pull-right" style="color: #1f0dc2;">@Model.PageModel.AverageSalesPercent%</span>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Схема в кратце]

[image: Вот что происходит, если размеры не одинаковые]

Comment: А можно просто между ними всё имеющееся пространство распределить? Или нужна именно максимальная ширина?

Comment: @Qwertiy нужно именно максимальная ширина и высота. Это нужно, чтобы текст не наезжал друг на друга, как то так (прикрепил фото выше)

Comment: В общем, я не понимаю вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy у контейнеров A,B,C,D размеры расчитываются по содержимому, ну и нужно сделать так, чтобы размеры всех четырех контейнеров (ширина и высота) имели максимальные значения, среди всех детей, таким образом будет эффект, что все контейнеры ВСЕГДА будут одинакового размеры - ровные. По заданию должно быть четыре контейнера, расстояния между которыми равно и сами они должны быть одинакового размера (но так, чтобы текст нигде не наезжал друг на друга)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том что и в таблице и во flex контейнере, и в большинстве других контейнеров ширина одних элементов зависит от ширины других. Это значит что если мы добавим 4 дочерних элемента, то контейнер рассчитывает параметры (ширину и высоту) каждого на основе всех остальных. Теперь если мы сделаем у всех размеры максимального элемента, то весь расчёт который сделала таблица или flex собьётся, и это уже будет не то что подразумевает flex контейнер или таблица. Например рассчитав максимальное и сделав все элементы под его размер у нас элементы могут вылезти за пределы границы, или перейти на следующую строчку в зависимости от настроек flex.

Если же где-то в вакууме вычислять ширину и высоту, то конечно можно у всех элементов взять максимальный, но возникает другая проблема. Например мы будем брать `div`. Дело в том что `div` по умолчанию жадный и берёт всю строку, а это нам не подходит.

То есть ваша задача не имеет нормального решения в том виде в котором вы её сформулировали.

Возможно вам следует искать другое решение. Например брать фиксированную высоту и ширину заведомо умещающую все элементы. Либо весь имеющийся экран разделить на четыре равных прямоугольника или квадрата. Это как раз стандартное решение, и оно легко реализуется например на bootstrap или чистым css.

Такое решение предлагаю

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 4px;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .item {
    width: calc(25% - 12px); /* 4 блока это 5 отступов *2px (margin) = 10px + запас для внешнего контейнера */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 999px) {
  .item {
    width: calc(33% - 10px);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .item {
    width: calc(100% - 4px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">текст</div>
  <div class="item">текст текст текст текст текст текст текст </div>
  <div class="item">текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст </div>
  <div class="item">текст текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: В том то и проблема, что не могу брать фиксированные значения. Каркас должен подстраиваться под любые устройства... Тут сплошной Bootstrap. Я как раз и делю область на 4 равных куска, через бустраповские стили разметки

Comment: @Xambey я там дописал в конце. Сделайте адаптивную bootstrap таблицу равномерно бьющую на 4 части на больших экранах а на маленьких по 1-2 элемента. Сейчас в пример напишу..

Comment: ок, спасибо за идею! А я уж начинал думать о костыле через js... Жду пример))

Comment: @Xambey пример напишу, только чуть подождать придётся, так как что-то комп глючит, и тут не всё так просто оказалось.

Comment: @Xambey сделал. Поиграйте с размером экрана в этом примере.

Comment: @Xambey В примере все блоки равного размера, при этом они адаптируются под размер экрана. Конечно более точные настройки для размеров экрана вам необходимо сделать самому - media блоки.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

По-моему тут два варианта решения проблемы - 1. Медиа запросы 2. Не указывать высоту элементов (при разной величине контента - установить высоту побольше, но тут нужно немного поработать "напильником")
В общем @media вам в помощь. И статичные width-heigh лучше не использовать.