# Помогите сделать каталог на флексах

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста, перерыл кучу источников внятного объяснения этому так и не нашел.

Как сделать каталог на флексах?
Хочу сделать, например, 3 позиции на одной строке и следующие 2 на другой строке.Как сделать это без отдельных разрывов,с нормальным позиционированием, чтобы потом можно было использовать в адаптивной верстке?

Как делать каталог на флекс элементах например 4 на 2 (4 -1 одна строка,2-вторая строка), 3 на 3 и т.д., как правильно расположить элементы?

Прилагаю свой код:

```css
.section1 {
display: flex; 
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.section2 {
   display: flex;

}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 900px;
    display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}
.block {

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:10px solid;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section1">
<div class="block">

</div>

<div class="block">

</div>


<div class="block">

</div>
</div>
    <div class="section2"> 
    <div class="block">

</div>
<div class="block">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Пытался разбить все на 2 секции по ширине в `100%` - не вышло. Свойство `flex-wrap` тоже не помогло.

Comment: Писал не так давно ответ, может и вам поможет, суть что флексы сделаны адаптивными и вывод в много строчек - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/764151/205037

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так.. Это при условии, если задать фиксированую ширину классу .gallery (контейнера галереи)

```css
.gallery {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 border: 3px solid red;
 margin: 25px auto;
 width: 680px;

}
.gallery__item {
 display: block;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: #000;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
 <div class="gallery__item"></div>
 <div class="gallery__item"></div>
 <div class="gallery__item"></div>
 <div class="gallery__item"></div>
 <div class="gallery__item"></div>
 <div class="gallery__item"></div>
</div>
```

Пустой div: `<div style="width:100%"></div>`

```css
.gallery {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 border: 3px solid red;
 margin: 25px auto;
 max-width: 680px;

}
.gallery__item {
 display: block;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: #000;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
 <div class="gallery__item"></div>
 <div class="gallery__item"></div>
 <div style="width:100%"></div>
 <div class="gallery__item"></div>
 <div style="width:100%"></div>
 <div class="gallery__item"></div>
 <div class="gallery__item"></div>
 <div class="gallery__item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо мужик.как я не догадался.точно!можно было так разбить!спасибо!