# Как на флексах сделать адаптив?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, flexbox

[Ссылка на код.](https://jsfiddle.net/30f4L82p/7/)

В общем, есть такая задачка. На флексах нужно сделать адаптив. Не получается у меня никак: хочу, чтобы при сужении экрана столбцы уходили вниз один за другим и в конце превратились в `1 коламн. мб`?

Код HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <section class="container">


    <div>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    <br>Labore, quod, minus! Deleniti odio delectus in, labore ratione deserunt. 
    Quo sequi veniam, pariatur cupiditate molestiae
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    <br>Labore, quod, minus! Deleniti odio delectus in, labore ratione deserunt. 
    Quo sequi veniam, pariatur cupiditate molestiae
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>Labore, 
    quod, minus! Deleniti odio delectus in, labore ratione deserunt. Quo sequi 
    veniam, pariatur cupiditate molestiae
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>Labore, 
    quod, minus! Deleniti odio delectus in, labore ratione deserunt. Quo sequi 
   veniam, pariatur cupiditate molestiae
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>Labore, 
   quod, minus! Deleniti odio delectus in, labore ratione deserunt. Quo sequi 
   veniam, pariatur cupiditate molestiae
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
   <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
   <br>Labore, quod, minus! Deleniti odio delectus in, labore ratione deserunt. 
    Quo sequi veniam, pariatur cupiditate molestiae
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    <br>Labore, quod, minus! Deleniti odio delectus in, labore ratione deserunt. 
    Quo sequi veniam, pariatur cupiditate molestiae
        </p>
    </div>
    </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Код CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}

*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    section {
        padding-top: 50px;
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 7rem;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

.section1 img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.section1 h2 {
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
.section1 .col-md-4 {
    text-align: center;
}

.section1 p{
    width: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}


.section1 .btn {
    margin-top:30px;
}

.navbar-img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.img-block {

    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

    widows: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Для этого есть flex-wrap: wrap, или flex-flow

Comment: на флексам адаптив можно запилить медиа-квирями!

Comment: Мой ответ, как раз делал так - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/764151/205037 , поиграйтесь с ответом, при разных размерах идёт разное количество колонок.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ppMRwj

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .col {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex magni cumque, nisi quos perferendis assumenda commodi amet itaque quas, voluptas consequatur et dicta ducimus doloribus dolores magnam sed inventore veniam?</div>
  <div class="col">Libero quasi deleniti numquam nobis, sapiente aspernatur voluptate velit dolor, atque veniam temporibus dolorem, perspiciatis repellat voluptatum sit architecto? Ad commodi iusto et ab quod eveniet obcaecati vero impedit perferendis!</div>
  <div class="col">Eos nemo quos cum excepturi quae, perferendis dicta, unde molestias maiores quidem, ducimus minus aspernatur. Fugiat dolor soluta ad ea recusandae veritatis commodi dolore ullam rerum minima, suscipit assumenda accusamus?</div>
  <div class="col">Porro ullam, non at unde aliquid facilis labore sint distinctio nobis autem molestiae corporis? Dolor repellendus eius temporibus possimus ducimus, tempora facilis rerum at nostrum, exercitationem non? Vero, id ex?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: не работает,не понял принцип. все также остается при минус 500

Comment: @FaceBook в смысле не работает? Вы смотрели пример на codepen? Если размер экрана меньше 500px блоки выстраиваются в одну колонку